# CodeIgniter PHP Library load template not working in AWS server

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am facing to export dynamic data in word document format. Any idea?

I did tried in AWS server using CodeIgniter framework and same things are working with XAMPP server.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a79oP.png)

Comment: You need to be more specific with your problem, include the code you’re currently using and any errors you get.

Comment: yes getting error which related with zip archive